# I restored sql server database with CDC tables,but have no data in the CDC tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am  used this query restore database:

```
Restore Database sqldbdemo_1 
from disk = 'l:\sqldbdemo.bak' 
with move 'SQLDBPool' to 'L:\SQLDBdemo1.mdf',
move 'SQLDBPool_log' to 'F:\SQLDBdemo_log1.LDF',keep_cdc
```

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2421/restoring-a-sql-server-database-that-uses-change-data-capture/

Comment: Your restore statement looks like what I'd expect it to be (i.e. has the `keep_cdc` clause on it). How are you determining that there's no data in the CDC tables? Also, are you sure that there *should be* data in there?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it was the old backup (older than retention period (5 days?)) and clean up job was performed just after DB restoration